# XAMARIN: Why does "TAG" work in my MainActivity, but not in another class?

Tags: android, xamarin

for debugging, I use this code in my Main Activity:

```
        Log.Debug(TAG, "No longer listening for location updates.");
```

This works totally fine, but as soon as I am in another class this line does not work anymore. It says that "TAG" does not exist in the current context. Of Course did i import the same using directives... So what could cause that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just make a new String TAG there. Or change TAG to MainActivity.TAG.

Comment: `TAG` is a String  variable of your `MainActivity`.

Comment: damnit... thanks xD